# How to add a runonce startup script?

Tags: scripts, startup

I'd like to add a runonce start-up script on Ubuntu which is expected to be run after the network interfaces have been initialized and before any user logs in. So which is the appropriate place to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Upstart in Ubuntu

Create a .conf file in /etc/init

For example your-runconce.conf

```
description "runonce script"
author "your name"

start on starting network-manager


exec /path/to/executable/script
```

This will create a upstart script that will runonce after network-manager is up.